# A Logical Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, cipher

Here is a block of cipher text C:

28 49 3d 57 2f 48 20 7c 20 7b 4e 7d 3a 49 27 57 27 48 20 45 29 20 3c 2d 2d 20 28 7b 5f 5a 7d 3a 58 20 7c 20 7b 36 5f 27 30 27 38 5f 7d 3a 58 20 41 29

Please evaluate this text and return to me it's value. There aren't many steps to get through but you'll need some knowledge and logic. If you can't get through a particular step, at least post your partial progress so someone else can hep out.

In the interest of improving this puzzle, allow me add a light hint regarding the method of getting the answer: Assuming C is the initial text provided and D is the resulting text after manipulations,

D="ROT180"(A^-1(H^-1(C)))

From there, you will need to use logic to evaluate D and provide the final answer.

Comment: Converting from hex to ASCII, I got
(I=W/H | {N}:I'W'H E) <-- ({_Z}:X | {6_'0'8_}:X A)

Comment: I believe the stackexchange formatting may have modified your text. I did not foresee this being a problem. Are there escape characters for this formatting?

Comment: @NeedAName You can use backticks for that like this `<don't screw up>`.

Comment: @AJL you may want to repost your result with the escape characters mentioned by mmking.

Comment: Ah, wait, the text Z}:X | {6 was enclosed in underscores, making it italics.  It's actually `(I=W/H | {N}:I'W'H E) <-- ({_Z}:X | {6_'0'8_}:X A)`.  AHHH  IT WORKED!  Sorry...

Comment: This puzzle is not a good example of a question we'd like to see on this site. For more information please see this meta question: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: @warspyking, I appreciate your comment! Reading that post, I found that I do several of those things in my puzzles. Most of this was from fear that I'm making my puzzles too easy for the site by including too many hints. But having read that info, I'll try to make better posts in the future. Thanks again for the info

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help

Comment: What did you manage to get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I interpret this answer to be

> True

Because

> The statement appears to say $\forall_{x\in\{-8,0,-9\}}x\in\mathbb{Z}^{-}\implies\exists_{H,M,I\in\mathbb{N}}H/M=I$; that is, "(for all $X$ in the set $\{-8,0,-9\}$, $X$ is in the set of negative integers) implies (there exists an $H$, $M$, and $I$ in the natural (counting) numbers such that $H/M = I$). The second statement has no $X$ so we can reduce the statement to: there exists an $H$, $M$, and $I$ in the natural numbers such that $H/M=I$.  $6$, $3$, and $2$ are all natural numbers and $6/3=2$; thus the statement is true.

I'm not sure I've interpreted all the symbols correctly,  but I feel confident it's at least a partial answer.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in accepting; you interpreted all of the symbols correctly and got the correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer, following the hint given:

`D="ROT180"(A^-1(H^-1(C)))` is very clear in its meaning:

> "un-Hex" the ciphertext, "un-Ascii" it, then rotate it 180°.

As already stated in the comments, the first two actions give:

> `(I=W/H | {N}:I'W'H E) <-- ({_Z}:X | {6_'0'8_}:X A)`

And the last action results in this:

> [image]

Now, I can definitely recognize something here, but the notation is throwing me off quite a bit. I'll try to figure out the missing pieces.

Comment: The confusion may be coming from the symbol '|'. In my formal logic courses, this symbol was used like a 'such that', used to separate the conditions of variables involved and the claim being made about them. I'm not sure how common the use of that symbol is, however.

Comment: Actually I got that, I'm more concerned about the `:` and the generic meaning of the line.

Comment: The colon I understand to be a viable stand-in for the symbol epsilon (which could not be included in my encoding for the obvious reason)

Comment: Ok, I thought so and it makes sense. Now I only have to figure out the rest

Comment: if it doesn't divulge too big a hint, how do we interpret "{ }".  Since colon is epsilon which I did not know before.

Comment: {} represents a set. What is inside the braces are the contents of the set.